# Howto override or add genlist item style?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I want to override genlist item style with my own:

```
group { "elm/genlist/item/1text/default";
  data {
     item: "texts" "elm.text";
  }

rect { "elm.clipper";
  scale: 0;
  desc { "default";
     color: 249 0 249 255;
     min: 360 120;
     max: 360 120;
  }
}

text { "elm.text";
  scale: 1; 
  clip_to: "elm.clipper";
  desc { "default";
    text { 
      text: "elm.text";
      size: TEXT1_SIZE;
    }
  }
}
```

Now my problem is that if I don't set `min` and `max` for the clipper, I get this:

[image]

If I set to be `360x120`, it seems the current items are larger than the "default" genlist style. And the last item goes more down than others (ie, it gets an offset downwards):

[image]

So, is there anybody on this living planet who has an *example* of a customized genlist item style?

What the ... shall I use in the EDC to be it as high as the default style???

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/ui/efl/component-custom/

Please refer to the above doc.

The genlist way to harder than customized other widgets like button, radio, or check.

I recommend that you implement your requirements as much as possible using the styles supported by default.

Comment: Thx. I wanted to use default styles, but there is no way to scroll the text with `default` style. Even, with `1text` style (which honestly I don't really like), there is no way of changing the scrolling speed.

Comment: For the customized genlist item, I had to use `min: 0 100; scale: 1` to be the same as `default`.

Comment: Also, with the above EDC, my genlist item is not calling the function "item is selected" when I touch anywhere else except the label itself. Ie, left or right to the label doesn't call the selection function.

Comment: about the selection,
it's because your edc doesn't have any area who can be clicked and propagate event to the item.
I think one bg rectangle(should visible and scale, mouse 1, color can be transparent) need to get the click event.

Comment: about the marquee speed,
we answered in the topic, please check them.
you can see the genlist item's edc in efl-theme-tizen-wearable/wearable-circle/widgets/genlist.edc

Comment: Thanks @JadeLee, transparent bg trick worked for selection. Could you please tell me where can I find "efl-theme-tizen-wearable/wearable-circle/widgets/genlist.edc"?

Comment: "The genlist way to harder than customized other widgets like button, radio, or check." I recommend then to create a proper documentation for customizing the genlist as there is nothing out there (except some old 404 pages) :)

Comment: Can you please look at my other Tizen issue with SVG: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65939893/svg-is-not-displayed-after-migrating-from-tizen4-to-tizen5-5-neither-in-emulato Sorry for asking this here, but there is no available forum where I can get in touch. JIRA is not working, facebook is handled by a bot. forum is not sending email